# How to add different datasource to two different colums in c#

Tags: c#, listview, datasource

I have a ListView in which I have added two columns. One column is simple and one column has the Free 3 of 9 Font as I want to convert the values of column one into BarCode and then show them into the second column. I want to fill the Datasource of the ListView with the help of a List.
Now my question is that how can I set the Datasources of a single column of ListView as I have to convert the values of that columns to BarCode and then show it in other column.

I am now only setting the Datasource of the whole of the ListView as I have added the columns after that.

My code is as follows what I am trying to do

```
      private void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         List<string> SerialNumberList = new List<string>();
         int SerialNumberStart = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(StartSerialBox.Text, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty));

         int SerialLimit = Convert.ToInt32(LimitBox.Text);
         for (int i = 0; i < SerialLimit;i++ )
         {
           SerialNumberStart++;
           SerialNumberList.Add("S" + SerialNumberStart);
         }
        for (int j = 0; j < SerialNumberList.Count;j++ )
        {

            Adapter.insertserialnumbers(SerialNumberList[j], DateTime.Now.ToString());

        }
         radListView1.DataSource = SerialNumberList;
       }
```

I want that both columns should have separate List as Datasource and only the Font of the second column should be changed.

Comment: What list view do you use exactly? I'm confused with `radListView1` name. If you mean WinForms `ListView`, then it is a bad choice for data binding.

Comment: I am using the ListView from the Rad controls. I have tried to do the same thing with the DataGridView but I am unable to bind the datasource of DataGridView with List<string>. If you have any idea then you can guide me as well that which shoud I use and then How can I bind the Datasource of either controls with the List

Comment: Basically in simple words I wanted to show two columns whose datasource should be a separate List<>. The font of column one will be simple but the Font of the other column will be Free 3 of 9 (BarCode)

Comment: Honestly, I can't understand, why do you need separate lists. These lists will contain different data?

Comment: No I am using the single list<> and want to assign that List<> to the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample with `DataGridView`:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGridView = new DataGridView
        {
            AutoGenerateColumns = false,
            DataSource = new List<string>
            {
                "Red",
                "Green",
                "Blue"
            }
            .Select(s => Tuple.Create(s))
            .ToList()
        };

        var columnA = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        {
            HeaderText = "Column A",
            DataPropertyName = "Item1"
        };

        var columnB = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        {
            HeaderText = "Column B",
            DataPropertyName = "Item1",
        };

        columnB.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 14);

        dataGridView.Columns.Add(columnA);
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(columnB);

        Controls.Add(dataGridView);
    }
```

`DGV` can't be bound to the list of strings directly, because data binding for the particular column needs a data property name, which to bind to. So, I'm using a wrapper here (a `Tuple<string>`).

Is this what you want?

P.S. Of course, you can use designer as well. The sample creates `DGV` in code to show, what's happening.